# How to set state of cart when no items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my E-Commerce project, the products are stored in localStorage. componentDidMount() gets all these products from localStorage and displays it. How to state the state or condition when no products are available.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
        this.setProducts();

        // Gets all products in cart from localStorage
        this.setState(
                () =>{
                   return {cart: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myCart'))}
                },
                () => {
                    this.addTotal()
                })
       // How to set the condition when no products in Cart?   
    }

// Set all the products on Main Page
setProducts = () => {
       let tempProducts = [];

       storeProducts.forEach(item => {
            const singleItem = {...item};
            tempProducts = [...tempProducts, singleItem];
       }); 
       this.setState(() => {
        return {products: tempProducts};
       });
    };

// Here products are added to cart and stored in localStorage
addToCart = (id) => {
        let tempProducts = [...this.state.products];
        const index = tempProducts.indexOf(this.getItem(id));
        const product = tempProducts[index];
        product.inCart = true;
        product.count = 1;
        const price = product.price;
        product.total = price;
        this.setState(() => {
            return { products: tempProducts, cart: [...this.state.cart,
            product] };
        },
        () => {
            this.addTotal();
            localStorage.setItem('myCart', JSON.stringify(this.state.cart))
        });
    }
```

I have also tried to make following changes, but, no effect. In componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount() {
      if(this.state.cart.length > 0) {
            this.setState(
                () =>{
                   return {cart: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myCart'))}
                },
                () => {
                    this.addTotal()
                })
        } else {
            this.setState(() => {
                return {cart:[]}
            })
        }

}

// Clear Cart
clearCart = () => {
        this.setState(() => {
            return {cart:[]}
        }, () => {
            this.setProducts();
            this.addTotal();

        })
        localStorage.removeItem('myCart')
    }
```

When I remove code of setState (shown in the beginning) from componentDidMount() displays empty cart message, which is expected else, if the cart is cleared and refreshed browser throws 'cart.length' error. Any possible solution?

Answer (score 3):

`JSON.parse` will return an object. It depends on your data structure but there is no cart.lendth for the object. So that is your first problem. So for the below example, I store the parsed value as an array.

Also, if `state.cart` is not initiated, there is no `.length` property for it.

For your second problem have a look at the below version of your `componentDidMount`:

```js
    componentDidMount() {
      if(Array.isArray(this.state.cart) && this.state.cart.length) {
            const cart = localStorage.getItem('myCart') || [];
            this.setState({cart: [JSON.parse(cart)]}), this.addTotal);
      } else {
            this.setState({ cart:[] });
      }
    }
```

Again, it depends on your implementation, but you might need to initiate the component's state with `cart:  localStorage.getItem('myCart') || []` or doing what I have done above. I'm basically checking if cart is an array && it has length then parse it otherwise initiate the array.

Comment: It gives me error 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions' at this line -> this.setState(() => {cart:[]})

Comment: @Pranav Edited the answer

Comment: OK, but I don't know cart clears even its stored in localStorage. Logically the flow of your code seems to be right, but, the code is not working for me

Comment: @Pranav How you set cart localStorage and is there any situation where you remove/purge the localstorage?

Comment: Yes on clicking Clear Cart, items are removed from localStorage. I can provide the code.

Comment: even though your code didn't worked for me, but, it helped me. Thanks

Comment: @Pranav Good to hear

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution as below

```
const cart = localStorage.getItem('myCart')
this.setState({cart: JSON.parse(cart) ? JSON.parse(cart) : []}, this.addTotal)
```

Just modified the code and works perfectly without any issues